# Hibernate endless queries - jersy?

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

Lets say i have 2 tables (mysql)
table A:
idA,name,phone

table B:
idB,data1,data2,idA

in table B: idA is used as foreign key and it is configured via mysql workbench.

now, i am trying to use Hibernate with jersy (building some kind of rest API)

and I am using netbeans as my IDE.

finally if got:

1. A.java
2. B.java
3. A.hbm.xml
4. B.hbm.xml

B.hbm.xml

```
<many-to-one name="a" class="DataTypes.A"> 
    <column name="idA" length="45" not-null="true"  />
</many-to-one>
...
```

and in B.java

```
public class B implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Integer idB;
     private A a;
     ...
}
```

A.java

```
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String idA;
    private String 
private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>(0);
     ....
}
```

and some part in A.hbm.xml

```
<set name="bs" inverse="true">
    <key>
        <column name="idA" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="DataTypes.B" />
</set>
```

the main problem is when i uses hibernate to get all entries of table A the result is hibernate queries for all A records and for each record it looks for it's B's (Set) after it got its B (because its foreign key) its looks again for its A and so on..

2 questions :) :
is there any solution for this recursion? or should i cut this circular reference?
is my database model is OK? (foreign key)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have some specific setup for (non) lazy loading? Such a recursion should not happen, such a bidirectional association should be valid...

Comment: no i didn't. but it might be the problem :), i just wrote to dursun that i am using jersy so when jersy converts the pojo to json it calls for all the getters (like getB() ... )

Answer (score 0):

You can specify lazy loading for those relationships: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazyproperties

Answer (score 0):

you can configure your b.hbm.xml as followed;

```
<many-to-one name="a" class="DataTypes.A" fetch="select"> 
    <column name="idA" length="45" not-null="true"  />
</many-to-one>
```

and a.hbm.xml;

```
<set name="bs" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key>
        <column name="idA" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="DataTypes.B" />
</set>
```

it should work now

Comment: hii dursun, i'm using jersy ( great framework for building rest api). this framework knows to take an serializable object and convert it to json. when creating the json, the framework actually calls to all the getter's methods of the pojo. that means that the lazy fetching will eventually accrues.